Integration of MoveIt2 with Ignition Gazebo in ROS2 Humble
I am trying to integrate MoveIt2 with ignition Gazebo (Fortress) through the gz-ros2-control to do motion planning of a custom robot arm. I am attaching a video for reference to show the issues I have atm.
Issue 1: The robot seems to be going to the target state in both gazebo and Rviz but the TF tree remains at the vertical home position (rather than moving to the target).
Issue 2: If I do motion planning for the second time, the robot seems to be starting from its initial vertical home position rather than from the current position.
All the relevant packages are available at moveit2_ign_gazebo. The simulation is started using ros2 launch continuum_robot_moveit_config bringup.launch.py sim:=true.
I have followed the moveit_setup_assistant tutorial to generate the my_robot_moveit_config. Then added these
<plugin>ign_ros2_control/IgnitionSystem</plugin>
<gazebo>
          <plugin filename="ign_ros2_control-system" name="ign_ros2_control::IgnitionROS2ControlPlugin">
              <parameters>$(find my_robot_moveit_config)/config/ros2_controllers.yaml</parameters>
              <robot_param>robot_description</robot_param>
              <robot_param_node>robot_state_publisher</robot_param_node>
          </plugin>
</gazebo>

If I have missed any relevant info to solve this issue, pls fell free to comment.
Thanks
